# Global functions in Lucee/Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee

I am trying to create global functions in Lucee. I have followed the directions [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1776-creating-globally-accessible-user-defined-functions-in-coldfusion-safer-version.htm) and have it "Kind of" working. Inside of Application.cfc I placed the following code:

```
public void function onRequest() {
    URL.IsInternalUser = function() { return (SESSION.user.ID ?: 0); };
}
```

This seems to work fine in some cases but if we need to access this function in a subdirectory that contains an Application.cfc that does not have the function re-defined it will error out saying the function doesn't exist.

The ultimate goal I am trying to achive is to have a `cfc` file that contains several user defined functions and then have them accessible throughout the entire application without redefining things over and over again.

Is there a better way to accomplish what we want? I ask this because on the page I referenced earlier in the comments section there is a quote:

> I concur. Wouldn't surprise me to see it somewhere else in the future.
>
> What I like about **Railo's** method is that it is completely sandboxed.
>   Host A's tags & functions libraries never cross/conflict with Host B's
>   libraries unless they're put into the global server folders. It's the
>   same way for the virtual file system too and pretty much everything
>   else (datasources, etc).

It specifically mentions Railo having a way to create UDF but I can not find any documentaion on this anywhere. Since we are using Lucee which is a fork of Railo I figure it must have what Railo has for creating UDF. Hoping someone that reads this can help me out and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Railo/Lucee support custom functions. You can declare them in `/WEB-INF/{railo|lucee}/library/function/` of the site. Save the function in a `.cfm` file and name the file the same as the function. The server needs a restart after creating new functions. [Here is Railo's blog post about it.](http://web.archive.org/web/20160304055918/http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/railo-3-1-building-your-own-built-in-function)

Adobe ColdFusion doesn't support this AFAIK. So you have to store your functions in the `SERVER` scope here.

Comment: Wouldn't the WEB-INF directory get overwritten every time the server gets restarted?

Comment: No, the WEB-INF is only created once with the start of the Railo/Lucee service. The directory then is kept and stores settings.

Comment: You don't have to store anything in the server scope for Adobe Cold Fusion.  You just have to put the cfc in the default location for custom tags.

Comment: @DanBracuk Just tested this in CF10 and it's not recognized, neither functions in a cfcomponent/cfc nor in a cfm.